# Move an element by clicking on a link with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Is it possible to affect one element by another element? I want to move `.box` element when I click on the link `a.link`.

I tried this, But couldn't get it to work. What should I write at `link:active`?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.box
{
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    border:solid red 5px;   
}

.link:hover
{
    color:red;
}

.link:active
 {
    color:grey;
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>
   <a href="#" class=link >CLICK ME</a>
   <div class=box></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The title is quiet different from the actual question. it may cause misconception. Please edit the title to indicate the issue better. However, you could find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919044/css3-transition-on-click-using-pure-css/21919261#21919261 Check the 2nd method.

Comment: Your question is poorly worded, and I don't understand it well enough to edit it. Could you revise your question so it makes more sense? Perhaps using language from the answers you found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible using sibling/child selectors.  The selector has to include the element you're taking action on.

When you click on `.link`, you want `.box` to move.  They're next to each other, so you can use the adjacent sibling selector `.link:active + .box`.

You can use transitions to animate the movement.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/2P4aA/2/