# Pure CSS method of running an animation through on click

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to recreate the material design ripple effect in pure CSS, and I have the animation prepared. The problem is, I can't make the animation run all the way through when the element is clicked. I've tried with transitions ([attempt 1 demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGGEJG), [attempt 2 demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JddreR)), but neither of these will run all of the way through.

The other more likely method is with CSS3 animations (I'm not worried about browser support right now). I have the animation keyframes ready, but I've never worked with animations very much before and I don't see a way to run the animation upon clicking.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    background-size: 1% 1%;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  70% {
    background-size: 1000% 1000%;
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    background-size: 1000% 1000%;
  }
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    background-size: 1% 1%;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  70% {
    background-size: 1000% 1000%;
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    background-size: 1000% 1000%;
  }
}

.button {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, #FFF 0%, #FFF 10%, transparent 10.1%, transparent 100%);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-animation: ripple 0.6s 0s normal forwards infinite running ease-in;
  animation: ripple 0.6s 0s normal forwards infinite running ease-in;
}

.button:active::after {
  /*Somehow the animation needs to run on click only, and then run all the way through*/
}
```

```html
<div class="ripple button"><a>Click this</a></div>
```

Somethings I've thought about but have been unable to make work include changing the animation delay, making the `::after` transparent using `opacity`, and using the animation timing function.

Comment: Use javascript to toggle a class with the animation.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919044/css3-transition-on-click-using-pure-css

Comment: or possibly use the :active pseudo selector. But personally, js would be best here, since other alternatives use hacks (like using an invisible checkbox, for example)

Comment: I can't use JS here, which is why I specified CSS only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out but you need to use jquery to keep the button active , i didn't used jquery therefore hold the click;

```css
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    background-size: 1% 1%;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  70% {
    background-size: 1000% 1000%;
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    background-size: 1000% 1000%;
  }
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    background-size: 1% 1%;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  70% {
    background-size: 1000% 1000%;
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    background-size: 1000% 1000%;
  }
}

.button {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}



.button:active:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, #FFF 0%, #FFF 10%, transparent 10.1%, transparent 100%);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-animation: ripple 0.6s 0s normal forwards infinite running ease-in;
  animation: ripple 0.6s 0s normal forwards infinite running ease-in;}
```

```html
<div class='ripple button'><a href=''>hell</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've have done this another way:
With `:focus` the styles stays active. You can view it here:
http://codepen.io/jonnitto/pen/OVmvPB?editors=110

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos: This is obviously not a link-only answer. Please do not abuse your flagging privileges.