# jQuery rotate div onclick +/-90

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick, rotation

I was wondering if there is an easy way to rotate a div +90 degrees after clicking it and by clicking it next time it returns to 0 degrees (so that the div rotates -90 degrees). 
Since I couldn't find anything I was looking for your help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020904/how-to-rotate-a-div-using-jquery

Comment: If supporting IE < 9 is not a concern, [it could be achieved with pure CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919044/css3-transition-on-click-using-pure-css/21919261#21919261). Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/tonukekesu/1/edit)

Comment: you can also use : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452477/rotate-div-text-after-clicking-on-button-using-jquery-and-css

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use toggleClass and apply css transform to that class:

```js
$('button:first-of-type').on('click', ()=> $('#rotate').toggleClass('rotated'));

const btn = document.querySelector('button:nth-of-type(2)');
const block2 = document.querySelector('#rotate2');

btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>block2.classList.toggle('rotated'));
```

```css
body {text-align: center;}
#rotate, #rotate2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border-top: 10px solid black;
  transition: transform .2s ease;
  margin: 20px auto;
  color: #fff;
}

.rotated { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>rotate block</button>

<div id="rotate">jQuery</div>

<button>rotate block</button>

<div id="rotate2">Vanilla</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was excactly what I was looking for! 
I made it a little bit smoother with CSS3 `transition`

For example: `-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/btdoxjf6/2/)

Comment: Great, happy to help. Instead of adding 'all',  you can also add the transition to the transform only:
`#rotate{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: transform 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: transform 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: transform 1s ease;
    -o-transition: transform 1s ease;
    transition: transform 1s ease;
}`

Comment: It is probably the best solution without using any plug-ins or function.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use CSS for rotating the `div`. And for `+-90` you have to add/remove to the `div`, this can be easy achieved with `toggleClass`. Adding this behaviour inside a `click` event will result something like below.

```js
$('.square').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('rotate-90');
});
```

```css
.square {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.rotate-90 { 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square">
  
</div>
```