# How to rotate glyphicon without using javascript?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using twitter bootstrap and I have `glyphicon-menu-up`. When i click on the icon it collapse and expand the contents.

However when i click on the icon i want to rotate the icon by 180 degree using CSS. I know how to do it using Javascript. But i wanted to do it only using CSS.

Here is the partially working [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8ogce235/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example uses JavaScript anyway to trigger the collapsed state on the div. Either way if you watch the markup from the dev console you can see that a `.collapsed` class is added to the trigger (in this case your button) when it is clicked.

You can modify your current css with this to get it working:

```
.collapsed .glyphicon-menu-up {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/8ogce235/1/)

Answer (score 0):

As this similar QA suggests, if you want a CSS only solution, try :active.

[CSS3 transition on click using pure CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919044/css3-transition-on-click-using-pure-css)