# jQuery scale on click addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get the `.post__input--not-set` to `scale` on click. Tried adding a CSS transformation without luck.

```js
$(".post__input--not-set").hide();
$('.btn-class').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("new");
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-check fa-pencil-alt');
  $(".post__input--not-set").addClass('animate').toggle();
});
```

```css
.btn-class {
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  background: blue;
}

.new {
  background-color: green
}

.post__input--not-set {
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 5s;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red
}

.post__input--not-set.animate {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="btn-class"><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i></a>
<div class="post__input--not-set"></div>
<div class="post__input--not-set"></div>
<div class="post__input--not-set"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could remove `$(".post__input--not-set").hide()` from your js, and toggle only the `transform`. Does this work for you?

```js
$('.btn-class').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("new");
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-check fa-pencil-alt');
  $(".post__input--not-set").toggleClass('animate');
});
```

```css
.btn-class {
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  background: blue;
}

.new {
  background-color: green
}

.post__input--not-set {
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 5s;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red
}

.post__input--not-set.animate {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="btn-class"><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i></a>
<div class="post__input--not-set"></div>
<div class="post__input--not-set"></div>
<div class="post__input--not-set"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Transitions don´t work if the element is initially gone. The `display: none` style actually removes the elements. So when you toggle the `display` property they are recreated with the `animate` class already and there´s nothing *changing* to be animated.

The only (but wrong) way to make it work would be to display the elements first, force a reflow (to force the browser to paint them without the `animate` class), and then set the `animate` class.

The correct ways would be

- to have the elements always displayed (using `visibility` or `opacity` to hide them), but that´s not always possible because *they will be there* occupying space and receiving events,
- to use JS to create new elements before each transition and destroying them after,
- or to use JS to do the whole animation.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting discussion: [CSS3 transition on click using pure CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919044/css3-transition-on-click-using-pure-css)

Possible solution:

```js
   $(".post__input--not-set").hide();
$('.btn-class').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("new");
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-check fa-pencil-alt');
  $(".post__input--not-set").addClass('animate').toggle();
  if ($(".post__input--not-set").css("transform") == 'none') {
    $(".post__input--not-set").css("transform", "scale(0)");
  } else {
    $(".post__input--not-set").css("transform", "scale(1)");
  }

});
```

```css
    .btn-class {
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  background: blue;
}

.new {
  background-color: green
}

.post__input--not-set {
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 5s;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="btn-class"><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i></a>
<div class="post__input--not-set"></div>
<div class="post__input--not-set"></div>
<div class="post__input--not-set"></div>
```